# double free or corruption (fasttop):

Tags: c++

I wrote the following piece of code and got the error mentioned above

Can someone tell me where i am going wrong

Thanks.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "sstream"
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
     std::string temp1 = "454552354772";
    char arr[16];
    memcpy(arr , &temp1 , temp1.size());
    std::string temp2;
    memcpy(&temp2 , arr , temp1.size());
    std::cout<<temp2;

}
```

the error i got was

```
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000016c5010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x80a46)[0x7fa91d359a46]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsD1Ev+0x20)[0x7fa91dc78290]
./a.out[0x400bc9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fa91d2faea5]
./a.out[0x400a09]
```

Comment: Copying to the address of a `std::string` isn't possible. Not without invoking all kinds of undefined behavior.

Comment: i am only copying the data from the address pointed by the std::string rite??

Comment: I meant the second `memcpy` statement. You copy from an array straight into a `std::string` object. Don't do that.

Comment: How else can i copy the value of the array into the std::string??

Comment: Using the methods suggested by ForEveR's answer.

Comment: @user2454413 you have `std::string` as both first and second arguments for `memcpy`. Obviously, you copy data to it at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot work with objects of `string` class this way.

```
memcpy(arr , &temp1 , temp1.size());
```

should be

```
temp1.copy(arr, temp1.size());
```

And

```
memcpy(&temp2 , arr , temp1.size());
```

should be

```
std::string temp2(arr, temp1.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` is a dynamically allocated container. You should rarely use it as a destination for `memcpy`. In your code, there is no memory allocated for `temp2`. The workaround is to use `string::reserve` to preallocate memory.

However, there is usually no need to mix C-code (`memcpy`, `char[]`) with C++-code (`std::string`, `std::cout`). Apparently, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy from the location of the string(it also contains functions, other data etc.), and copy 16 bytes, you end up with alot of unusable data.

You want the first character in the string, so you would do this:
`memcpy(arr, &temp1[0], temp1.size());`

This would effectively copy it.
When you want to do the opposite(copy to the string), why not just do this?
`std::string temp2(arr, temp1.size());` or `std::string temp2((const char*) arr);`